# What are all the allowed `xsi:type` values in the xml's from Magento2

Tags: magento2, xml, di

In Magento 2 (almost) all arguments listed in xml files have an attribute `xsi:type` that determine how the value of the argument is iterpreted.
For example, in `di.xml` file of the backend module there is this:

```
<argument name="scopeType" xsi:type="const">Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT</argument>
```

this means that the value of the argument `scopeType` is the value of the constant `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT`

or this one

```
<argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Theme::root.phtml</argument>
```

this means that the value of the argument `template` is the string `Magento_Theme::root.phtml`.

What are all the possible values of this `xsi:type` attribute?

Comment: Have you ever tried to use a `static` instead of a `const` for such an argument? I can't seem to find a type that works for a `static` field in my class :-(

Comment: No. I didn't. I don't even think there is support for `static`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I've found all types by checking `<xs:extension base="argumentType"` in *.xsd files.

`lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Data/etc/argument/types.xsd`, these are **base types**:

- "**array**"
- "**string**"
- "**boolean**"
- "**object**"
- "**configurableObject**"
- "**number**"
- "**null**"

`lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd`, can be found in **di.xm**l files:

- "**object**"
- "**init_parameter**"
- "**const**"

`lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd`, can be found in **layout *.xml** files:

- "**options**"
- "**url**"
- "**helper**"

`Magento/Ui/etc/ui_components.xsd`, can be found in **UI components' *.xml** files:

- "**constant**"
- "**url**"

Answer (score 16):

According to my researches, here is what I've found:

The argument interpreter is created in the `lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory.php` :

```
protected function createArgumentInterpreter(
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\BooleanUtils $booleanUtils
) {
    $constInterpreter = new \Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Constant();
    $result = new \Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite(
        [
            'boolean' => new \Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Boolean($booleanUtils),
            'string' => new \Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\StringUtils($booleanUtils),
            'number' => new \Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Number(),
            'null' => new \Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\NullType(),
            'object' => new \Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\DataObject($booleanUtils),
            'const' => $constInterpreter,
            'init_parameter' => new \Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ArgumentInterpreter($constInterpreter),
        ],
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom::TYPE_ATTRIBUTE
    );
    // Add interpreters that reference the composite
    $result->addInterpreter('array', new \Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType($result));
    return $result;
}
```

In this code, you can clearly see that different interpreters are used based on the type attribute of the argument `\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom::TYPE_ATTRIBUTE`:

- **boolean** => `\Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Boolean`
- **string** => `\Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\StringUtils`
- **number** => `\Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Number`
- **null** => `\Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\NullType`
- **object** => `\Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\DataObject`
- **const** => `\Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Constant`
- **init_parameter** => `\Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ArgumentInterpreter` (note that this one takes the `\Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Constant` as parameter and not the constructor parameter)

Also an extra interpreter is added on the fly to handle array types:

- **array** => `\Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType`

Note: it seems like the `init_parameter` type is only used in the `app\code\Magento\Store\etc\di.xml` to initiate some constants:

```
<argument name="xFrameOpt" xsi:type="init_parameter">Magento\Framework\App\Response\XFrameOptPlugin::DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG_X_FRAME_OPT</argument>
...
<argument name="isCustomEntryPoint" xsi:type="init_parameter">Magento\Store\Model\Store::CUSTOM_ENTRY_POINT_PARAM</argument>
...
<argument name="runMode" xsi:type="init_parameter">Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE</argument>
<argument name="scopeCode" xsi:type="init_parameter">Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE</argument>
```