# Magento 2 - What case I use di.xml and How to use di.xml for module?

Tags: magento2, di

In Magento 2, What case I use `di.xml` and How to use `di.xml` for module?

Anyone knew, please show me step by step.

Comment: You can get more info from magento officialy site : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`What case We use di.xml ?`

- We can use di.xml for ( rewrite ) preference of a particular class.
- We can send new or replace the existing class [arguments](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103606/what-are-all-the-allowed-xsitype-values-in-the-xmls-from-magento2).
- Use plugins to do some stuff before, after and around the function
- By using virtualTypes creating a sub-class of another class.

Let us take a quick example from Magento 2 customer module.

**1.Preference**

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface"
            type="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository" />
```

Above code, When someone asks you to instantiate a `Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface` it will instantiate a Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository
    object (the type attribute).

Class preference configuration is not just for interfaces we can change the actual classes as well.

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerManagement"
            type="Magento\Customer\Model\customModel" />
```

You can create 'customModel' class for 'CustomerManagement' and do the changes. Class preference system as a replacement for the class rewrite system.

http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_preferences

**2. Arguments**

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group" shared="false">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="groupManagement" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface\Proxy</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

In th above code, We are  sending object as an argument, we are saying system to insert "Proxy" class as an object with the name of `groupManagement`.
Also, we can use Arguments for replacing the existing argument too.

http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_argument_replacement

**3. Plugin**

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Visitor">
    <plugin name="catalogLog" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Plugin\Log" />
</type>
```

In the above code ,     `public function clean($object)` in visitor class is called after  public function `afterClean(Visitor $subject, $logResourceModel)` which is in Log class.

**4 Virtual Types**

Creating a virtual type is sort of like creating a sub-class for an existing class.

For more note please go through the practical examples some I mentioned as links from Alan, by practice you can get more clear experience.

Hope this helps.... :)

Comment: have you any idea about the set configuration with ifconfig in di.xml for enable/disable module process? if you about that please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: Very useful information.

Comment: How does someone learn all these stuff?

Comment: So the <preference> instead of call the class in "for", it call the class in "type" or something? i'm still confusing about this. @@

Comment: oh nvm, i found this really good answer here.
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/
:)