# What is the use of "mapping" node in di.xml in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configuration, di, object-manager, mapping

I am using Magento 2.2.5

have a look on file

> vendor\magento\module-sales\etc\di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mapping" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="country" xsi:type="object">Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CanUseForCountry</item>
            <item name="currency" xsi:type="object">Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CanUseForCurrency</item>
            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="object">Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CanUseCheckout</item>
            <item name="internal" xsi:type="object">Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CanUseInternal</item>
            <item name="total" xsi:type="object">Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\TotalMinMax</item>
            <item name="zero_total" xsi:type="object">Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\ZeroTotal</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

there is a node having a name "***mapping***". Does anyone have any idea about its use?

I have read the question [Magento 2 - What case I use di.xml and How to use di.xml for a module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111845/magento-2-what-case-i-use-di-xml-and-how-to-use-di-xml-for-module)
and Alan storm's article ["Magento 2 Object Manager Argument Replacement"](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_argument_replacement/)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check `Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationFactory` of the `construt`

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CompositeFactory $compositeFactory, array $mapping)
    {
        $this->compositeFactory = $compositeFactory;
        $this->mapping = $mapping;
    }
```

Second argument `array $mapping` in the array you will get all your argument which you defined in `di.xml`

**EDIT**

from the `construct` `$this->mapping` you will find all of the objects in the array which you defined in `di.xml`.

For example If you set `<argument name="mappingtest" xsi:type="array">` then you need to define `construct`  as

```
 public function __construct(
\Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CompositeFactory $compositeFactory, array $mappingytest
) {
    $this->compositeFactory = $compositeFactory;
    $this->mapping = $mapping;
}
```

Here `$mappingytest`

Comment: I have seen this, but unable to understand the logic of this file. You mean to say if we use `mapping` node, It'll add an array parameter in respective type class here 'Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationFactory'.

Comment: Is this related to the last argument we pass in all model's constructor the **array $data = []**?

Comment: Yes, it is related to last parameter as mentioned in my answer `mapping`

Comment: Still you have any query? @Knight017 :)

Comment: No, actually I have concluded the answer by editing your answer. But somehow it is not showing now.

Answer (score 2):

> The object manager injects the Magento\Core\Model\Url implementation
>   class wherever there is a request for the
>   Magento\Core\Model\UrlInterface in the global scope.

**Multiple validation for different modules with filed.**

```
<argument name="mapping" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="country" xsi:type="object">Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CanUseForCountry</item>
                <item name="currency" xsi:type="object">Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CanUseForCurrency</item>
                <item name="checkout" xsi:type="object">Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CanUseCheckout</item>
                <item name="internal" xsi:type="object">Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CanUseInternal</item>
                <item name="total" xsi:type="object">Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\TotalMinMax</item>
                <item name="zero_total" xsi:type="object">Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\ZeroTotal</item>
            </argument>
```

Now check **SpecificationFactory** file for Business logic.

> vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Checks/SpecificationFactory.php

```
class SpecificationFactory
{
    /**
     * Composite Factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CompositeFactory
     */
    protected $compositeFactory;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $mapping;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CompositeFactory $compositeFactory
     * @param array $mapping
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CompositeFactory $compositeFactory, array $mapping)
    {
        $this->compositeFactory = $compositeFactory;
        $this->mapping = $mapping;
    }

    /**
     * Creates new instances of payment method models
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return Composite
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function create($data)
    {
        $specifications = array_intersect_key($this->mapping, array_flip((array)$data));
        return $this->compositeFactory->create(['list' => $specifications]);
    }
}
```

**It validates the mapping data module wise.**

```
$specifications = array_intersect_key($this->mapping, array_flip((array)$data));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Conclusion**

The conversation with **@Keyur Shah** and the suggestion of **@Jignesh Khunt** conclude that you can add configurations in `di.xml` and can access in type class here `Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationFactory`. In last param array `$mapping` in below files constructor.

> vendor\magento\module-payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationFactory.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Payment\Model\Checks;

/**
 * Creates complex specification.
 *
 * Use this class to register predefined list of specifications that should be added to any complex specification.
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class SpecificationFactory
{
    /**
     * Composite Factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CompositeFactory
     */
    protected $compositeFactory;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $mapping;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CompositeFactory $compositeFactory
     * @param array $mapping
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\CompositeFactory $compositeFactory, array $mapping)
    {
        $this->compositeFactory = $compositeFactory;
        $this->mapping = $mapping;
    }

    /**
     * Creates new instances of payment method models
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return Composite
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function create($data)
    {
        $specifications = array_intersect_key($this->mapping, array_flip((array)$data));
        return $this->compositeFactory->create(['list' => $specifications]);
    }
}
```

The argument node (here "**$mapping**") must be member variable of the type class(`Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationFactory`).

Then the data you pass in `di.xml` will be accessible and usable in your factory class and you can customize the logic. I have used to initialize dynamic class according to data available in **$mapping array** (without rewrite or plugin/prefrence) using this feature.