# di.xml constant type vs init_parameter

Tags: magento2, di

I see in the `di.xml` files from the core that some of the arguments have the type `init_parameter` but the values of the parameters are all constants.

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="appMode" xsi:type="init_parameter">Magento\Framework\App\State::PARAM_MODE</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

or this one

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\Cache\State">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="banAll" xsi:type="init_parameter">Magento\Framework\App\Cache\State::PARAM_BAN_CACHE</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

and many others.
But from what I see in the interpreter associated to `init_parameter`, the constant interpreter is used `Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ArgumentInterpreter::evaluate`

```
public function evaluate(array $data)
{
    return ['argument' => $this->constInterpreter->evaluate($data)];
}
```

But the result is a bit different from the `Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Constant::evaluate`

```
 public function evaluate(array $data)
{
    if (!isset($data['value']) || !defined($data['value'])) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Constant name is expected.');
    }
    return constant($data['value']);
}
```

Can someone explain please how the `init_parameter` type works and how everything happens under the hood?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found it.
For `const` the value of the specified constant is used.
For `init_parameter`, the value provided must be a constant name but the actual value used is the value of `$_SERVER[constant value here]`.

In the method `Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory::resolveArgument` metohod you will find [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php#L131)

```
    else if ($argument === (array)$argument) {
        if (isset($argument['argument'])) {
            if (isset($this->globalArguments[$argument['argument']])) {
                $argument = $this->globalArguments[$argument['argument']];
            } else {
                $argument = $paramDefault;
            }
        } else if (!empty($argument)) {
            $this->parseArray($argument);
        }
    }
```

`$argument['argument']` looks very similar to what the init parameter interpreter returns.
And if there is a value with the key `$argument['argument']` in the `globalArguments` member that one is returned.
`globalArguments` member is populated with the arguments with which the bootstrap class is initialized.
So for the web application these arguments are `$_SERVER`. (see index.php).

Conclusion:

```
<argument name="appMode" xsi:type="init_parameter">Magento\Framework\App\State::PARAM_MODE</argument>
```

means that the parameter named `appMode` will have the value `$_SERVER[Magento\Framework\App\State::PARAM_MODE]` if it is set.
Which means `$_SERVER['MAGE_MODE']`

Comment: I think this information should be added to the official documentation. Thanks for the detailed exploration. :)

Answer (score 3):

[What are all the allowed `xsi:type` values in the xml's from Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103606/what-are-all-the-allowed-xsitype-values-in-the-xmls-from-magento2)

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html

[image]

**Node format**: `<argument xsi:type="init_parameter">{Constant::NAME}</argument>`
**Description**: Global argument of an application represented by `Constant::NAME` is looked up and passed as an argument.
**Possible values**: Constant the global argumentcontaining name

**Node format**: `<argument xsi:type="const">{Constant::NAME}</argument>`
**Description**: Constant::NAME passed as an argument.
**Possible values**: All constant names are possible.

Let's take below example.

**magento\vendor\magento\module-store\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="cache" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config</argument>
        <argument name="runMode" xsi:type="init_parameter">Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE</argument>
        <argument name="scopeCode" xsi:type="init_parameter">Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

**magento\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\StoreResolver.php**

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $runMode;

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $scopeCode;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository
 * @param StoreCookieManagerInterface $storeCookieManager
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface $cache
 * @param StoreResolver\ReaderList $readerList
 * @param string $runMode
 * @param null $scopeCode
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository,
    StoreCookieManagerInterface $storeCookieManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface $cache,
    StoreResolver\ReaderList $readerList,
    $runMode = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
    $scopeCode = null
) {
    $this->storeRepository = $storeRepository;
    $this->storeCookieManager = $storeCookieManager;
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->cache = $cache;
    $this->readerList = $readerList;
    $this->runMode = $scopeCode ? $runMode : ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE;
    $this->scopeCode = $scopeCode;
}
```

Idea is simple. You can directly pass your variables & it's value from `di.xml` file. Instead of defining that values in ur Model.

So u just need to initialize ur variables & u will get value from ur `di.xml`

Hope it helps

Comment: It doens't really help because it does not answer my question. I asked for the difference between const and init_parameter in behavior.