# Magento2 di.xml inject config value

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, di

Is it possible to inject a value from store config, or alternatively from a helper class (similar to m1 layout xml) into a class using `di.xml`?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/103618/146) you can only inject something that will be interpreted as a helper method in layout files but not in `di.xml`.
I tried it with `helper` for `di.xml` and indeed it crashes.
I don't know if you can add a store config value, but here is an alternative of doing it.

make your class constructor accept a string parameter that will be the config path to the value you need and also add as a dependency an instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface`.

```
protected $scopeConfig;
protected $configPath;
protected $yourConfigValue;
public function __construct(,
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    $configPath,
    ....
) {
   $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
   $this->configPath = $configPath;
   $this->yourConfigValue = $scopeConfig->getValue($configPath);
}
```

If you are inside a block you don't need to add `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` as a dependency. It is already added in the abstract block and you can access it as `$this->_scopeConfig` but only after you call `parent::__construct()`.

Then you can add in `di.xml` this

```
<type name="your\class\here">
     <arguments>
         <argument name="configPath" xsi:type="string">path/to/config</argument>
     </arguments>
</type>
```